# How to pass "css properties" with html templating system

Tags: html, css, nunjucks

I'm building a component library with nunjucks and some times I need to pass varialbes to change for example a background image, nunjucks doesn't parse css files and I ended up setting inline styles like so:

**Includes the component and pass the background image**

```
{% set comp = { 'image': 'foo.jpg' } %}
{% include 'component.njk' %}
```

**component.njk file**

```
<div class='comp' styles="background-image: url({{ comp.image }});"></div>
```

I could put it inside < style > tags inside the component but it's not html standar

**This is not valid html :S**

```
<style>.comp { background-image: url({{ comp.image }}); }</style>
<div class='comp' styles=""></div>
```

To solve that I'm trying to append component styles tags inside the header tag.

Is there any gulp plugin or something?
Is there any better solution to this?

I found a [cool "plugin" for nunjucks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nunjucks-append) to append code from subviews but it seems outdated :S

Thansk so much!

Comment: Do you want to reuse your style in different projects and change the `background-image` or other styles for the whole project or do you need to also change the style on individual sites of your project?

Comment: I'll use the component across the whole project with differents values of background image.

Comment: I would be happy if I could use this, but just works in firefox:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_scoped.asp